# Excel VBA Sub, define Range over multiple Rows and Columns or Columns in Data Table

Tags: excel, vba

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894030/turn-cell-range-into-array-for-grantaccesstomultiplefiles-excel-vba) answer, I have a macro in Excel for Mac in order to grant file access to multiple files. The file paths are stored as text in columns W to Z in this example:

```
Sub requestFileAccess()
    Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean
    Dim filePermissionCandidates As Variant
    filePermissionCandidates = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("First").Range("W8:W200"))       
    fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)
End Sub
```

This works fine for one column, i.e., I can define `Range("W8:W200")`.
But `Range("W8:Z200")` doesn't work. 
How would I do this?

Or, even better, since the values are in a Data Table, ideally I would want the macro to refer not to `Range("W8:Z200")`
but rather to `Range("Tablename[Columnname1]")` ... etc.
so I don't have to modify it if new rows are added. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating named ranges.  Simply select a whole range of cells, sequential/matrix or more sporadic, and type a name into the field (as shown below) into the **"Name Box"** field next to the formula bar ...

**Matrix**

[image]

**Sporadic**

[image]

Then from your code, you can simply reference that range and all of it's cells ...

```
Dim objRange As Range
Set objRange = Range("MyRange")
```

When you add rows or columns or even singluar cells to that range, they will be picked up automatically.

To edit your range, use the below function or alternatively, just insert rows or columns within the range as you would do normally when wanting to add data to pre-existing areas within a sheet.

[image]

Example ...

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim objRange As Range, objCell As Range

    Set objRange = Range("MyRange")

    For Each objCell In objRange
        Debug.Print objCell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

With the above, just make sure you have the "Immediate" window open within VBA to see the results of the debug.

In your case, try this ...

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim bFileAccessGranted As Boolean, objRange As Range, objCell As Range, arrValues() As Variant, lngIndex As Long

    Set objRange = Range("MyRange")
    lngIndex = -1

    For Each objCell In objRange
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrValues(lngIndex)

        arrValues(lngIndex) = objCell.Value
    Next

    bFileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(arrValues)
End Sub
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Brad, I've followed your instructions, but I get a `Run-time error '13'`? Any ideas?  I've defined the Name as you suggest, called it "Filepaths" and then added to the code above like this:  
    `Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean  | 
    Dim filePermissionCandidates As Variant  | 
    Dim objRange As Range  | 
    Set objRange = Range("Filepaths")  | 
    filePermissionCandidates = Application.Transpose(objRange)`

Comment: Can you debug it to the filePermissionCandidates = “Application.Transpose” line to make sure it all works up to that point? Basically, put a breakpoint there and then check your objRange variable to see what its value is.

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to debug?  I'm sorry, I'm completely ignorant when it comes to VBA :(

Comment: This is probably the easiest way for me to show you ... https://www.google.com/search?q=gow+to+debug+in+excel+vba&rlz=1CDGOYI_enAU590AU590&oq=gow+to+debug+in+excel+vba&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5972j0j9&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Did you say it was working before adding my code?  I ask because "Application.Transpose" doesn't exist for  me.  "WorksheetFunction.Transpose" does though.  I suspect it's that line causing you drama.  If it is that line, we can talk about how to fix your issue there, let's determine if that is in fact the issue though.

Comment: Yes, well, it was working when I specify `filePermissionCandidates = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("First").Range("W8:W200"))`, i.e., when I directly specify the Range explicitly.   I am on Excel for Mac, so not sure if that's why it's different?  The debug message tells me "Type mismatch"

Comment: Ohhhhhh, you're on Mac.  Funnily enough, I did wonder that but didn't ask the question because I thought it was a long shot.  Let me try some code on my Mac and I'll get back to you.

Comment: What version of Excel are you on?  I get the same on my Mac, Transpose exists under WorksheetFunction, not Application.  Bizarre!

Comment: What's the reason for needing to Transpose?

Comment: Version 16.16.7.   I am essentially using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894030/turn-cell-range-into-array-for-grantaccesstomultiplefiles-excel-vba) question, mentioned above, but now needed to expand it over multiple columns.

Comment: I have a slightly older version, but still not far back ... 16.16.3.  Sorry, hit enter, will add another comment.

Comment: Bottom line, if you need to be able to  then loop through each cell and probably just for a better implementation, I'd change this function "GrantAccessToMultipleFiles" to accept a Range and then you can use "For Each objCell in objRange" and then "varValue = objCell.Value" (or Text depending on formatting, but prob not a problem for you) within that for loop to give you each value.  That's what I'd do anyway.  You're essentially doing the same thing anyway but you're minimising the jump around each object.  Declare objCell as a Range.

Comment: I added an example to my answer.  That worked for me.

Comment: OK, yes, that gives me the right values .  But then what do I specify for the `fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(????)`  I tried to use objCell but I run into the "type mismatch" error again :(

Comment: I see this "GrantAccessToMultipleFiles" is a Mac thing.  I'll update my example.

Comment: Yeah, the whole thing is only necessary because of the stupid sandboxing on the Mac. In my Excel sheet I'm testing for the existence of files and the OS requires me to grant access to every single one independently ...

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if what I wrote will work so let me know.  To be honest, the Mac side of the equation is where I'm unfamiliar but at the end of the day, they're just objects with methods and properties and stuff I hope that works.

Comment: I now don't think that will work.  ha ha!  It creates a multi dimensional array.  Let me know, I do have another idea.

Comment: you're right, it doesn't  :(  My error is now '1004' "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed ..."

Comment: Ok, take 43, check the example now.  I modified it.  Cross your fingers!!!

Comment: Yay!!  Fantastic.  That did it. Thank you so much for figuring this out!!